# Display my wordpress plugin's number of downloads on site

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking for a way to display the download statistics of my plugin on my site.
More specifically, this one: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/magic-gallery/

is there a way to get the number of downloads from this page and display it on my own website?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, but that one wasnt working for me somehow. I solved it using the following plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/shortcode-plugin-download-counter/

This one isn't working OOB as well, but when you edit line 6 of shortcode-plugin-download-counter.php from:

```
"regexp" => '/<strong>Downloads:<\/strong>(.*?)<br \/>/'
```

to:

```
"regexp" => '/<strong>Downloads: <\/strong>(.*?)<br \/>/'
```

Then it works (just add a space after Downloads:).

Hope someone else finds it useful. This doesnt do anything but display the number of downloads but for me that was all I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're looking for a plugin to do this:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-developer-plugin-stats/